# help with using etoolbox with docsvlist and listadd

Tags: etoolbox

I am looking at `etoolbox` and not able to find why it gives this error. I am going over an example in the manual, which works. But when I made small change, I am getting an error.

This works:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}    
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\item #1}
  \docsvlist{{item1, 1},{item2, 2},{item3, 3}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

But the above example has the list right there inline.  I wanted to first create the list outside, and then process it separately. I found the command `listadd`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So used it to make a list and then run the `\begin{enumerate}` on the list, I get an error:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}    
\usepackage{etoolbox}    
\begin{document}    
\forcsvlist{\listadd\mylist}{ {item1, 1},{item2, 2},{item3, 3}}    
\begin{enumerate}
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\item #1}
  \docsvlist{\mylist}
\end{enumerate}    
\end{document}
```

Error is

```
    Command \end{enumerate} invalid in math mode. \end{enumerate}
```

Here is the example I was trying

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Question is: How can one create a list using `listadd` and process it separately using `\docsvlist{\mylist}` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `\dolistloop` to loop over the element of `\mylist`, not `\docsvlist`.  After you create it, `\mylist` is an internal list and no longer a comma separated list. The manual specifies that

> These lists use a special character as internal list separator.

and footnote 3 specifies:

> The character | with category code 3. Note that you may not typeset a list by saying `\listname`. Use `\show` instead to inspect the list.